# Create combinations of german words for spellchecking

Tags: c#, spell-checking

I'm implementing a SpellChecker in C# by using [Symspell](https://github.com/wolfgarbe/symspell).
It works pretty well, but I got some problems with some german words that contains the sharp s (ß) and umlauts (ä,ö,ü).
For example, when I'm checking for a word with an umlaut and writing the synonym for it instead(ä-> ae), it doesn't find any suggestions for it.
(Äpfe -> Did you mean "Äpfel"? and Aepfel -> no words found)

There are also words with more than one of these letters, so I'm looking for a method to create all combinations of a word and do a spellcheck with each of them.

e.g. someone writes "aeußerst": 
-> check for aeusserst, äusserst and äußerst

My approach is pretty naive and doesn't work well.

```
public static List<string> GetCorrectWords(string word2check)
    {
        var suggestedWordsList = SymSpell.Correct(word2check, "")


        if (suggestedWordsList.Count == 0) // If no suggestions could be found...
        {
            if (word2check.Contains("ä")) // ...check for mistakes with ä and ae
            {
                suggestedWordsList = SymSpell.Correct(word2check.Replace("ä", "ae"), "");
            }
            else if (word2check.Contains("ae"))
            {
                suggestedWordsList = SymSpell.Correct(word2check.Replace("ae", "ä"), "");                }

            if (word2check.Contains("ö")) // ... check for mistakes with ö and oe
            {
                suggestedWordsList = SymSpell.Correct(word2check.Replace("ö", "oe"), "");                
            }
            else if (word2check.Contains("oe"))
            {
                suggestedWordsList = SymSpell.Correct(word2check.Replace("oe", "ö"), "");                
            }


            if (word2check.Contains("ü"))
            {
               suggestedWordsList = SymSpell.Correct(word2check.Replace("ü", "ue"), "");
            }
            else if (word2check.Contains("ue"))
            {
                 suggestedWordsList = SymSpell.Correct(word2check.Replace("ue", "ü"), "");
            }


            if(word2check.Contains("ß")) // ...check for mistakes with ß and ss
            {
                suggestedWordsList = SymSpell.Correct(word2check.Replace("ß", "ss"), "");              
            }
            else if (word2check.Contains("ss"))
            {
                suggestedWordsList = SymSpell.Correct(word2check.Replace("ss", "ß"), "");               
            }

        }

        return suggestedWordsList;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could first save all special chars like the umlaute for each word in a list and then loop through all combination that are possible for your word

Comment: Can't you use third party APIs? or you yourself have to implement the mentioned functionality? The reason is that finding all combinations for words with more than six or seven characters is a time-consuming operation which reduces functionality. There are better ways to do so instead of combinations. Using Automatas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated:

> Aepfel -> no words found

Given that "Äpfel" is in the dictionary (or in the corpus from which the dictionary was created) this will only be the case if you have set *editDistanceMax=1*.

Option 1: In SymSpell you should set *editDistanceMax>=2* (Maximum Edit Distance). Then "Aepfel" will show the suggestion "Äpfel", because the **Damerau-Levenshtein edit distance** between the two terms is two.

Option 2: You don't need to create all umlaut-combinations of a word, if it contains several umlauts. You just need to consistently replace all umlauts ä/ö/ü/ß with their transcription ae/oe/ue/ss **both** during **dictionary generation** and **spelling correction**:

```
CreateDictionaryEntry(key.Replace("ä", "ae").Replace("ö", "oe").Replace("ü", "ue").Replace("ß", "ss")  , "")

Correct(word.ToLower().Replace("ä", "ae").Replace("ö", "oe").Replace("ü", "ue").Replace("ß", "ss")  ,"");
```

Comment: It's worth noting that for a search to correctly include results with German characters, search phrases with _ae_, _ue_ etc. should match _ü_, _ä_ etc. E.g. A search for _Mueller_ should return _Müller_